Отправка данных в SQLAchemy
я начал недавно изучать flask и вообще писать свои сайты начал не так давно. Я хочу добиться того, чтобы в мою базу данных отправлялись данные не только из формы, а простые переменные из html. То есть у меня есть страница с деталями покупок, где я с помощью js написал реализацию подсчета количества товара и его цены, а также добавил и форму, которую надо заполнить, только вот данные формы я смог отправить в таблицу, а количество и цену нет. Как мне это сделать? Если нужны какие-то дополнительные подробности или детали кода, то я могу их вам позже отправить
Попробовал поместить эти данные форму и добавить их в таблицу, но не получилось

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
